# CMake errors installing eigen 3.3.4

Tags: gcc, cmake, eigen

I am trying to install eigen with CMake. Following the CMake command, bottom of the output shows:

> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

The highlights of the CMakeError.log are below.
Normally, google gets me an answer pretty quick but I having trouble with this one.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wshorten-64-to-32'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/localadmin/apps/eigen/eigen-eigen-5a0156e40feb/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4154354821.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec4154354821/fast] Error 2

c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wenum-conversion'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/localadmin/apps/eigen/eigen-eigen-
5a0156e40feb/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec362406516.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec362406516/fast] Error 2

c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wc++11-extensions'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2110565347.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/localadmin/apps/eigen/eigen-eigen-5a0156e40feb/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec2110565347/fast] Error 2

c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-wd981'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/localadmin/apps/eigen/eigen-eigen-
5a0156e40feb/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1208176884.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec1208176884/fast] Error 2

c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-wd2304'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/localadmin/apps/eigen/eigen-eigen-
5a0156e40feb/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec853725866.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec853725866/fast] Error 2

c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-strict-ansi'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/localadmin/apps/eigen/eigen-eigen-
5a0156e40feb/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2089588030.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec2089588030/fast] Error 2

c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-Qunused-arguments'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/localadmin/apps/eigen/eigen-eigen-
5a0156e40feb/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec226858210.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec226858210/fast] Error 2

Compiling the Fortran compiler identification source file 
"CMakeFortranCompilerId.F" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c
```

Comment: What is your C++ compiler version? It may be too old.
Also, seems you're missing a fortran compiler - try adding with `sudo apt-get install gfortran`.

Comment: AFAIK you don't need cmake to install Eigen (that's for the doc and tests), you can just copy the headers wherever.

Comment: Line in CMake configuration output "Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!" means that error has been **reported above** this line. Find **actual** error message in the configuration output, and paste it into your question post.

Comment: valiano, your advice fixed it. If you post it as an answer, I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install gfortran`, as valiano suggested in the comments, fixed the issue.